# Javascript Promise: Resolve not Waiting

Tags: javascript

I have read other related posts and still am not understanding correctly how to use promises.

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    let promiseToGetResponses = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var indexData = new getIndexData();
        resolve(indexData);
        console.log('received ' + indexData.length);
    });

    promiseToGetResponses.then(function(data) {
        console.log('then data length ' + data.length);
        res.render('index', {rsvpsIn: data});
    }).catch(function() { });
});
```

Console shows this:

> received undefined
>   then data length undefined
>   returned 1 *** this is from a console.log inside the getIndexData().

The function is getting the data, but my promise usage is not waiting for it.

Thanks.

P.S.  I didn't know the getIndexData function was needed.  Here it is:

```
function getIndexData(){
    RSVP.find({response: 'in'}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // This will be a list of all responses to show in the view
        var rsvpsIn = [];

        if (data.length > 0) {
            // Use because the foreach loop below has async calls.
            var responseCounter = data.length;
            data.forEach(function(response) {
                var foundUser = User.getUserById(response.userId, function(err, user) {
                    var newRSVP = {userName: user.username, notes: response.notes};
                    rsvpsIn.push(newRSVP);

                    // decrement and if we are done, return list
                    responseCounter -= 1;

                    if (responseCounter == 0) {
                        console.log('returned ' + rsvpsIn.length);
                        return rsvpsIn;
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            return rsvpsIn;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should show `getIndexData`. Does it return a Promise?

Comment: What exactly is `indexData`?

Comment: You have to use a `.then()` callback, which would allow you to get the follow up request's response.

Comment: Your `getIndexData()` function doesn't return anything. That's the biggest problem, and probably the first you should try to fix.

Comment: indexData is a list of records from MongoDb.

Comment: Assuming RSVP.find returns a Promise iteslf, change the first line of `getIndexData` to `return RSVP.find(`

Comment: getIndexData returns the list from MongoDB.  See "return rsvpsIn" The RSVP.find() uses find() from Mongoose, which is a built-in function.  Basically, getIndexData is not completed before my promise.then() occurs.

Comment: rsvp.find has the signature of being callback based.  You should wrap that in a promise and return it.

Comment: The `return rsvpsIn` statement doesn't belong to the `getIndexData` function. It belongs to the function inside it. `getIndexData` has no return statement. I suggest you read this: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with RSVP but it appears to be callback based API, so you should wrap it in a promise and just use the promise directly:

```
function getIndexData(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        RSVP.find({response: 'in'}, function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err);

            // This will be a list of all responses to show in the view
            var rsvpsIn = [];

            if (data.length > 0) {
                // Use because the foreach loop below has async calls.
                var responseCounter = data.length;
                data.forEach(function(response) {
                    var foundUser = User.getUserById(response.userId, function(err, user) {
                        var newRSVP = {userName: user.username, notes: response.notes};
                        rsvpsIn.push(newRSVP);

                       // decrement and if we are done, return list
                        responseCounter -= 1;

                        if (responseCounter == 0) {
                            console.log('returned ' + rsvpsIn.length);
                            resolve(rsvpsIn);
                        }
                    });
                });
            } else {
                resolve(rsvpsIn);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

then just use it where you use the promise:

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    getIndexData().then(function(data) {
        console.log('then data length ' + data.length);
        res.render('index', {rsvpsIn: data});
    }).catch(function() { });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, everyone!  Thanks, Bryan, for showing me a re-write of the way it should be.  It helps my understanding a lot.

Comment: no problem. Next step is ditching promises and moving onto rxjs